# Vaadin - CSS Animation - Window not closeable

Tags: java, css, web, css-animations, vaadin8

I am developing a Vaadin Application and I have a bit confusing problem. At least it is confusing for me.
I am trying to build a Notification Window:

I press a Button -> A Window pops up.

So far not a big deal. But what a bad web developer would I be, if there isnt a nice animation, how the window comes in and leaves my page.
So I have my Keyframes here:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes window-open {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes window-open {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes window-close {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes window-close {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

And adding it to my scss selector like that:

```css
.nav-header-popup.v-window {
    
    [...]

    &.v-window-animate-in {
      @include animation(window-open 0.2s 0s);
    }

    &.v-window-animate-out {
      @include animation(window-close 0.2x 0s);
    }
  }
```

But, after I opened the Window by "UI.getCurrent().addWindow(w);", I somehow can't close it anymore.
Not with "w.close();" and not with "UI.getCurrent().removeWindow(w);".

So it looks for my like that the window is not attached to the UI. But how can this happen?
Or is it just me, who made the mistake? 
Or does someone know the solution to that problem.

Thanks in advance

Lucas

Comment: w.setCloseable(true)

Comment: No, that just adds a close button to the window. 

The Problem is, that the window gets shown, but is not attached to the UI

Comment: Maybe you need to push the changes to the client? Did you try to enable pushmode and then push the changes you made?